# MacroDroid : Using password in Intent

Tags: automation, macrodroid

I use [Adguard](https://adguard.com/en/adguard-android/overview.html) on my Pixel 6a. After a recent major upgrade, I noticed that the app is disabled erratically. Since this behavior is unpredictable, it is difficult to capture logs precisely for troubleshooting. I did manage once to capture and send them and they are taking too long to revert, so I thought of automation as an alternative.

[Adguard knowledgebase](https://adguard.com/kb/adguard-for-android/solving-problems/tasker/) suggests using Tasker set up as below. Adguard generates a password to authenticate the intent (preventing misuse by malicious apps) and this password needs to be a part of intent.

**Tasker Implementation**

[image: Tasker]

**MacroDroid Implementation**

I tried replicating the pattern in Tasker above in MacroDroid unsuccessfully. Please note that the password, package name and class are correctly entered. The action I am trying now when Adguard is running is

> `stop` stops the protection, no extra data required;

[image: MacroDroid]

The MacroDroid implementation does not work. **How do I fix this?**

Edit: If I change the target to *activity* instead of *broadcast*, I get this error in notifications

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd posted this in the MacroDroid forum and got a solution, which was tweaked and it works! Posting it here, so that it may help somebody else.

Essentially,one needs to declare the password as a local variable, with *auto detect* changed to *string*. However, for the person who suggested this, it worked in the default [auto mode](https://www.macrodroidforum.com/index.php?threads/macrodroid-using-password-in-intent.5207/post-29876)

YMMV!

[image]

The macro now looks like

[image]

Edit: After a few days of trial, the macro below works well.

[image]